# remove newline to be one index array

Tags: php, file, preg-replace

i have a data, like this :

```
>test
AAABBB
CCCDDD
EEEFFF
```

I want to take one index array. if in "print_r" to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => AAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFF
)
```

i have a code, like this :

```
$dataFQ = "data/fq.txt";

        $handleFQ = fopen($dataFQ, "r");
        if ($handleFQ)
        {
            while (($lineFQ = fgets($handleFQ, 4096)) !== false)
            {
                $lineFQ = explode("\t", $lineFQ);

                if (!empty($lineFQ[0][0]) && $lineFQ[0][0] != '>')
                {
                    $new_dataFQ[] = $lineFQ;
                }
            }
            if (!feof($handleFQ))
            {
                echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
            }
            fclose($handleFQ);
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($new_dataFQ);
        echo '</pre>';
```

how to modify it in order to be an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do in a simpler way...

```
<?php
$new_arr[] = implode('',(array_map('trim',array_slice(file('data/fq.txt'),1))));
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => AAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFF
)
```

Comment: FYI: [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) returns an array of every line of a file. Side note: dang you for being one step ahead of me @ShankarDamodaran...

Comment: why can there be "space"?
your code make be like this :
AAA BBB CCC DDD

Comment: @user3193610, I have changed the code. Can you test it ?

Comment: why i can't do it : substr($new_arr, 1, 5);
what should I do to be able to get "substr"?

Comment: `substr` does not work on arrays, it will work only on strings. what is the output you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
$data = file_get_content('data/fq.txt');
$trans = array('>test'=>'', "\n"=>'', "\r"=>'', ' '=>''); // and whatever you want
$result = array(strtr($data, $trans));
```

Comment: +1 for not relying on `preg_replace()`, however I think @ShankarDamodaran's answer is more elegant (both work equally well).

Comment: @user3193610: is `>test` always like this, and is it always one time in the file? at the begining?